# Generate list of parents-childs (recursive relationship) from Dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to build a list (HTML) with a recursive relationship.  The data is in a dataset but could converted to a data table if it's easier.

I don't know what's the best option to achieve this.  I was thinking about using nested repeaters.

Here's the data:

```
__ID__ | __NAME__  | __PARENT__     | __LEVEL__ 
1      | Patrick   |                | 1           
2      | Mark      |                | 1
3      | Scott     | 2              | 2
4      | Jason     |                | 1
5      | Julian    |                | 1
6      | John      | 6              | 2
7      | Steve     |                | 1
8      | George    | 1              | 2
9      | Robert    | 1              | 2 
10     | Rodney    | 8              | 3
```

Here the output I want to produce

```
- Patrick [1]
  - George [8]
    - Rodney [10]
  - Robert [9]

- Mark [2]
  - Scott [3]

- Julian [5]
  - John [6]

- Jason [4]

- Steve [7]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to write a recursive method.  The way it operates will depend on whether you want to have the method return the entire tree-structured list, or output the data as it reads it.  If you want to output the data as you read it, your code might look something like this:

```
Private Sub OutputTree(data As DataTable, parentId As String, indentationLevel As Integer)
    For Each row As DataRow In GetChildRows(parentId)
        OutputRow(row, indentationLevel)
        OutputTree(data, row("ID").ToString(), indentationLevel + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that you also implement a method called `GetChildRows` which returns a list of all the rows that contain the given parent ID.  It also assumes that you have a method called `OutputRow` which outputs the given row at the given indentation level.

Then, you could call the method like this:

```
OutputTree(myDataTable, nothing, 0)
```

If you want to build and return a tree structure, which is arguably the better approach, your code might look something like this:

```
Private Function BuildTreeNodes(data As DataTable, parentId As String) As List(Of MyTreeNode)
    Dim nodes As List(OfNew MyTreeNode)()
    For Each row As DataRow In GetChildRows(parentId)
        Dim node As New TreeNode()
        node.Row = row
        node.Children = BuildTreeNodes(data, row("ID").ToString())
        nodes.Add(node)
    Next
    Return node
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that you have defined a `MyTreeNode` class which would look something like this:

```
Public Class MyTreeNode
    Public Property Row As DataRow
    Public Property Children As List(Of MyTreeNode)
End Class
```

Then you could call the method like this:

```
Dim rootLevelNodes As List(Of MyTreeNode) = BuildTreeNodes(myDataTable, Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks Steven.  
I was initially planning to use a TreeView but soon realized how limited TreeView controls are.  I don't want the list to be in a table but rather wrapped within specific HTML tags (<ul>, <li>). That's why I thought that using nested repeaters would let me more flexibility when outputting the list.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment.  Are you saying that my examples won't work for you for some reason, or were you just provided additional information?

Comment: I was mentioning that the TreeView control (Tree structure) won't work in my case.  I want to output each item of the list within <li> </li> HTML tags (nested HTML list) and a TreeView control won't let me do so.  That's why I thought that the only other option was to use nested repeaters.

Comment: Are you under the false impression that my examples use the `TreeView` control?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your `__PARENT__`  of parent item is null.

```
private void TopItems(DataTable Data)
{
    DataView view = new DataView(Data);
    view.RowFilter = "itemParent IS NULL";

    foreach (DataRowView row in view)
    {
        response.write("parent text: " + row["text"].ToString() + 
                 "parent id: " + row["id"].ToString();
        AddChildMenuItems(Data);
    }
}


//This code is used to recursively add child items by filtering by ParentID
private void AddChildtems(DataTable Data)
{
    DataView view = new DataView(Data);
    view.RowFilter = "itemParent=" + parentMenuItem.Value;
    foreach (DataRowView row in view)
    {
        response.write("child text: " + row["text"].ToString() + 
                 "child id: " + row["id"].ToString();
        AddChildtems(Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kobe.  The only way to identify a parent (of parent) is the level which has to be 1. The null value is not guaranteed.  

I'm trying to output the list in HTML (in the markup code).

Comment: you can use stringBuilder instead of the response.write to write your html. and also can edit the view.RowFilter = "itemParent IS NULL"; to your filter.