# How to recursively generate a list of parent-child strings from an Adjacency List?

Tags: python, recursion, adjacency-list

### Summary:

I'm trying to make a recursive function that takes data from an adjacency list and converts it to dot notation.

### Details:

I have this data as a list of tuples (Python). The data is sorted by `id`, but that is the only limitation. There is no restriction that parents must be listed before children: for example, item #3 could have a parent that is item #7. There is also no (planned) limit to the number of generations.

```
id     name     parent  |  data = [
1      A        0       |          (1, 'A', 0),
2      B        1       |          (2, 'B', 1),
3      C        1       |          ...
4      D        2       |
5      E        2       |
6      F        3       |
7      G        2       |
8      H        6       |          ...
9      I        4       |          (9, 'I', 4)]
```

I want to return a list of strings in parent-child dot notation:

```
A
A.B
A.B.D
A.B.D.I
A.B.E
A.B.G
A.C
A.C.F
A.C.F.H
```

Notice that every name is displayed - other algorithms that I've found will only return items that have no children.

### Things I've tried:

#### Python Code:

Here's what I've got so far, based USF's Data Structure Visualizations [here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RecReverse.html).

```
if len(cat_list) == 0:
    return

for item in cat_list:
    parent_id = item[0]
    name = item[1]
    children = [_x for _x in cat_list if _x[2] == parent_id]

    if len(children) == 0:
        # then we're at the end
        return name
    else:
        sub_problem = cat_list[1:]
        sub_solution = create_categories(sub_problem)
        solution = "{}.{}".format(name, sub_solution)
        print(solution)
        return solution
```

But all this does is take one item and build it all the way back:

```
D.E
C.D.E
B.C.D.E
A.B.C.D.E
```

#### SQL:

If the data was stored in a SQLite database, and could get partially there with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    t1.name AS level1,
    t2.name as level2,
    t3.name as level3,
    t4.name as level4
FROM category AS t1
    LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.name = 'A'
```

But this has multiple issues:

1. not scalable to arbitrary depths
2. does not return intermediate depths

Because of these limitations, I've decided to implement the code in Python.

#### Research

I've looked at a bunch of different questions and websites, but none have given me the "Eureka" moment, hence why I'm asking here.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17858701/1354930) is pretty similar, but is in vb.net which I know nothing about. It also doesn't inform me on how to perform the concatenation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18030091/1354930) is also pretty similar, but again I don't know the language. Seems like the `Lookup` function could be pretty similar to a python dict...

Answer (score 1):

The data preparation step is a little hideous, because your IDs are starting from one we need a blocker element None at position 0:

```
original = [(1, 'A', 0),
            (2, 'B', 1),
            (3, 'C', 1),
            (4, 'D', 2),
            (5, 'E', 2),
            (6, 'F', 3),
            (7, 'G', 2),
            (8, 'H', 6),
            (9, 'I', 4)]
ids,data,parents = zip(*original)
data =[None]+list(data)
parents = [None]+list(parents)
```

This code will work once you get your input data in the right format:

```
ids = range(1,10)
parents = [None,0,1,1,2,2,3,2,6,4]
data =[None,"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]

def get_parents(node):
    if not parents[node]:
        return data[node]
    return get_parents(parents[node])+data[node]
for id in ids:
    print ".".join(list(get_parents(id)))
>>> 
A
A.B
A.C
A.B.D
A.B.E
A.C.F
A.B.G
A.C.F.H
A.B.D.I
```

Answer (score 0):

After a writing out each step on a piece of paper, I was able to come up with the following:

```
def generate_category_strings(cat_list, parent_item, sent_str, retlist=[]):
    """
    Concatenates categories together and returns a list of them.
    """
    if parent_item is None:
        parent_item = cat_list[0]
        retlist.append(parent_item[1])

    parent_id = parent_item[0]
    parent_name = parent_item[1]

    if sent_str is None:
        sent_str = parent_name

    children = [_x for _x in cat_list if _x[2] == parent_id]

    if len(children) == 0:
        # base case, no children
        return ["{}.{}".format(sent_str, parent_name)]
    else:
        for child in children:
            str_to_send = "{}.{}".format(sent_str, child[1])
            retlist.append(str_to_send)
            generate_category_strings(cat_list, child, str_to_send, retlist)
        return retlist
```

Running this on the original dataset:

```
data = [(1, "A", 0), (2, "B", 1), (3, "C", 1), (4, "D", 2),
        (5, "E", 2), (6, "F", 3), (7, "G", 2), (8, "H", 6),
        (9, "I", 4),
       ]

a = generate_category_strings(data, None, None)
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

prints:

```
A
A.B
A.B.D
A.B.D.I
A.B.E
A.B.G
A.C
A.C.F
A.C.F.H
```

Comment: did you check my answer? Is the ordering crucial?

Comment: I did see your answer, thank you. Ordering is not crucial, since I can just sort it after the fact. I wanted to avoid having to reshape the data prior to generating the strings.