# Recursively find all the parents of a child given list of dictionaries

Tags: python, recursion, tree, parent-child

Given a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{'id': '1', 'parents': []},
 {'id': '2', 'parents': ['1']},
 {'id': '3', 'parents': ['1', '2']},
 {'id': '4', 'parents': ['3']},
 {'id': '5', 'parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4']},
 {'id': '6', 'parents': ['4', '5']},
 {'id': '7', 'parents': ['4']},
 {'id': '8', 'parents': []},
 {'id': '9', 'parents': ['1', '8']},
 {'id': '10', 'parents': ['8']},
 {'id': '11', 'parents': ['5', '6']}]
```

I would like to build a function that recursively ends up giving back for every element all the parents.

for instance element 11 has two parents, 5 and 6 which also have respectively ['1', '2', '3', '4'] and ['4','5'] which also have....
So the total parents of 11 in this case are [1,2,3,4,5,6]

I started with somthing like this:

```
def total_parents(parentlist,tree):
    if parentlist == []:
        return
    total = []
    for parent in parentlist:
        total.append(next((element['parents'] for element in tree if element['id'] == parent), None))
    total_flatten = [item for sublist in total for item in sublist]
    total_flatten_set = list(set(total_flatten))
    return total_parents(total_flatten_set,tree)

for claim in tree:
    claim['total_parents'] = total_parents(claim['parents'],tree)
```

This does not work at all. after playing much around with the code and having a look to some recursion questions: [How to recursively generate a list of parent-child strings from an Adjacency List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606084/how-to-recursively-generate-a-list-of-parent-child-strings-from-an-adjacency-lis)

Comment: Does /questions/8673482/transitive-closure-python-tuples help? Does it help knowing the term `transitive closure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a dictionary as follows:

Your input is not a dictionary. It's a *list* containing 2-element dictionaries (that contains a lot of redundant information). If you could reformat your input, the function you're looking for is pretty straightforward.

Here's how you might construct your function if your input is a dictionary of the form: `{<id>: [<parents>]}`:

```py
parent_map ={
    '1': [],
    '2': ['1'],
    '3': ['1', '2'],
    '4': ['3'],
    '5': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    '6': ['4', '5'],
    '7': ['4'],
    '8': [],
    '9': ['1', '8'],
    '10': ['8'],
    '11': ['5', '6']}

def get_parents(parent_map, node_id):
    parents = set(parent_map[node_id])
    for parent_id in parent_map[node_id]:
        parents |= set(get_parents(parent_map, parent_id))
    return list(parents)
```

And here's how you could translate your original input data to the format used in the function above:

```py
single_dict = {x['id']: x['parents'] for x in list_of_dicts}
```

The shape and format of your input data has a tremendous effect on how effectively you're able to operate on it.

Comment: what is the symbol  |=  doing exactly? thanks.

Comment: `parents` is a set ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)). The `|=` operator take the set union of the argument and `parents` and assigns the result to `parents`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
data = [{'id': '1', 'parents': []}, {'id': '2', 'parents': ['1']}, {'id': '3', 'parents': ['1', '2']}, {'id': '4', 'parents': ['3']}, {'id': '5', 'parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}, {'id': '6', 'parents': ['4', '5']}, {'id': '7', 'parents': ['4']}, {'id': '8', 'parents': []}, {'id': '9', 'parents': ['1', '8']}, {'id': '10', 'parents': ['8']}, {'id': '11', 'parents': ['5', '6']}]
d = {i['id']:i for i in data}
def get_ids(_id, c = []):
   yield from d[_id]['parents']
   for i in filter(lambda x:x not in c+[_id], d[_id]['parents']):
      yield from get_ids(i, c+[_id])

r = [{**i, 'total_parents':sorted(set(get_ids(i['id'])))} for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'parents': [], 'total_parents': []}, 
 {'id': '2', 'parents': ['1'], 'total_parents': ['1']}, 
 {'id': '3', 'parents': ['1', '2'], 'total_parents': ['1', '2']}, 
 {'id': '4', 'parents': ['3'], 'total_parents': ['1', '2', '3']}, 
 {'id': '5', 'parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'total_parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}, 
 {'id': '6', 'parents': ['4', '5'], 'total_parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}, 
 {'id': '7', 'parents': ['4'], 'total_parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}, 
 {'id': '8', 'parents': [], 'total_parents': []}, 
 {'id': '9', 'parents': ['1', '8'], 'total_parents': ['1', '8']}, 
 {'id': '10', 'parents': ['8'], 'total_parents': ['8']}, 
 {'id': '11', 'parents': ['5', '6'], 'total_parents': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}]
```